# How can I produce a "floating" object below an inline element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slew of normal inline `<a>` links that I want to open up small "floating" objects on click. These objects would be simple HTML `div`s (with some CSS) that would load on top of the page and below the link. I don't want to use relative positioning which would push the page around and I can't think of a way to use absolute positioning to get the `div`s underneath the inline links. I currently envision toggling the display value of the objects from none to whatever and back. I'm open to ideas.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use absolute positioning with the parent set to relative. e.g.

```
<div id="container">
    <a href=...>hover me for floating!</a>
    <div class="floating">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
#container { position: relative; ... }
.floating { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; }
```

In the above example, the .floating div is absolute positioned, which means it is taken away from the normal flow (ie, no placeholding it). But it also relative reference to it's parent, which is the div#container in this case, so that, if you set the top and left position, it is actually calculated from the top-left corner of div#container rather than to the document body.

Comment: +1, just to clarify: `absolutely` positioned elements position themselves relative to the *closest parent that is `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`*.

Comment: And I'd add that this wouldn't, I think (from memory), validate as inline elements (<a>) can't contain block level elements (<div>).

Comment: @drthomas, the div is not within the a.

Comment: This might work… So basically, you'd put the inline link and its onclick-floating-absolutely-positioned-block-div-thing (not really an easy way to refer to that object) into a relatively positioned block container?

Comment: Right. just like the html segment in my post

Answer (score 0):

you can use "fixed" position:

```
<div style="position: fixed; left:100px; top:100px; background-color: white; height: 200px; width: 200px;"> ... </div>
```

**"fixed position"** --> Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the browser window. The element's position is specified with the "left", "top", "right", and "bottom" properties

Comment: I'm not sure that you quite getting my question. I don't want to position relative to the window. That's not hard. I am trying to position it below an inline link.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
<style="text/css">

  a {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
  }

  a span.pop_up_floaty_thing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 10em; /* or whatever  */
  }

</style>

<a href="..." title="...">Link text<span class="pop_up_floaty_thing">The pop up, floaty thing text</span></a>
```